# Playframework - Append JS outside the main.html

Tags: javascript, playframework

In Play Framework, it's usually have main.html with code like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>#{get 'title' /}</title>     
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" 
            href="@{'/public/stylesheets/main.css'}" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" 
            href="@{'/public/images/favicon.png'}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        #{doLayout /} 
    </body>
</html>
```

So when I have a view such as index.html, it's usually start with

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
```

And the index.html only contain the body part ( `#{doLayout /}` in main.html ).

I want to add javascript depend on page loaded (in page coffee.html I want to load water.js for example). Now I have to add it in main.html and loaded it all over the application.

1/ How can it be loaded from extended view (index.html)?

2/ In addition, how can I get the baseUrl value (like Zend framework) to pass to javascript variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with set and get tags.

If your main.html is like this

```
<title>#{get 'title' /}</title>     
#{get 'moreScripts' /}
```

Then in your different views you can set different JS. For example, index.html may have no JS, but coffee.html will have

```
#{set 'moreScripts'}
    <script src="@{'/public/javascripts/yourscript.js'}" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
#{/set}
```

Comment: I just tried and found that the "/" must be eliminate: #{set 'moreScripts' }
    <script src="@{'/public/javascripts/yourscript.js'}" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
#{/set}

Comment: Yes, you are right. The slash would have been closing off the tag, and ignoring the content. I have updated the answer to show the correction.

Comment: So what are the advantages to be gained by wrapping the script tag in the "morescripts" tag?  

Why not just include the script in coffee.html anyway, like you would with a "normal" html page ?

Comment: because, if you put it in the 'morescripts' tag, it injects that content into the head of the html document. If you just place it in the template, then it would appear in the html body.